# How to resume playing audio after the camera goes away?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avaudioplayer, observer-pattern

I'm working on an app that plays audio in the background while using other apps using an AVAudioPlayer. When the camera is opened the music is silenced but none of the methods in the AppDelegate for app lifecycle get called so I can't save the playlist position or the playback time for the song.

In addition when the camera is dismissed I would like to have the app resume playing background music but again I haven't found any callback method to allow my to observe this change.

Do you know how to observe that the camera did become active and that the camera was dismissed while the app is running in background mode?

Comment: How is the camera opened?

Comment: Using the slide up control panel is how i have been doing it.

Comment: That causes your app to go to the background. I just tested it and the appropriate app delegate method is called.

Comment: Maybe on your hardware not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i solved it.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleAudioSessionInterruption:)
                                                 name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification
                                               object:[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]];
```

Handle the interuption.

```
-(void)handleAudioSessionInterruption:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    //NSLog(@"%@",notification);

    NSNumber *interruptionType = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey]; //1 Interuption Start, 0 Interuption Ends
    NSNumber *interruptionOption = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionKey];

    if ([interruptionType integerValue] == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"Player %d interupted",playerNumber);
        // • Audio has stopped, already inactive
        // • Change state of UI, etc., to reflect non-playing state
        [self.playPauseButton setTitle:@">" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.playingAudio = NO;

        return;
    }

    if ([interruptionType integerValue] == AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded)
    {
        if ([interruptionOption integerValue] == AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume)
        {
            NSLog(@"Player %d Resume",playerNumber);
            [self.playPauseButton setTitle:@"||" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            self.playingAudio = YES;

            NSError *error = nil;
            AVAudioSession *aSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
            [aSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:&error]; //& means value at address
            [aSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
            //[aSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&error];
            //[aSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeSpokenAudio error:&error];
            [aSession setActive: YES error: &error];
            [self.audioPlayer play];
        }
        // • Make session active
        // • Update user interface
        // • AVAudioSessionInterruptionOptionShouldResume option
    }
```